# How to access pipe connection object in a thread of a process in python? Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multiprocessing

Following is my code

```
from multiprocessing import Process,Queue,Pipe
from threading import Thread
import time

p,q = Pipe()
def bcd(p):
    print p.recv()

def abc(p):
    t1 = Thread(target=bcd,args=(p,))
    t1.daemon = True
    t1.start()

p1 = Process(target=abc,args=(p,))
p1.start()

time.sleep(3)
q.send('test')
```

when `bcd()` is started as a thread, `p.recv()` doesnt print anything.
However, when i try to access `p` from `abc()`,
`p.recv()` works and prints `test`. Can someone explain this behaviour?

Comment: i have passed it to bcd `target=bcd,args=(p,)`

Answer (score 1):

You have to add some `time.sleep(...)` to give a `timeslice` to startup.
Second, you have to **hold** `def abc(...)` as long **alive** as `def bcd(...)` needs to reach and excute `print(p.recv())`.

This will working for me, for instance:

```
def bcd(p):
    print(p.recv())
    time.sleep(0.1)

def abc(p):
    t1 = Thread(target=bcd,args=(p,))
    #t1.daemon = True
    t1.start()

    while True:
        time.sleep(3)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p,q = Pipe()
    p1 = Process(target=abc,args=(p,))
    p1.start()

    time.sleep(3)
    q.send('test')

    p1.join(4)
    p1.terminate()
    print('EXIT main')
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 and 2.7.9***